# Node.js - displaying ESLint errors in terminal like create-react-app

Tags: node.js, express, logging, create-react-app, eslint

I'm working on a Node.js app using Express, and I want ESLint to display errors/warnings in the terminal with colors like the way "create-react-app" does.

There is a way to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eslint` npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Follow the instructions to create a .eslintrc file. You're IDE should automatically read this and show the errors/warnings

Comment: I'm using this package and everything works as expected (it's is showing the errors when I enter to the relevant files),
But I want it to display the errors on the terminal, and even if I not inside a file with warnings.